# How do I use Matplotlib to save an image generated with ggplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-ggplot

While this part works

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ggplot import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Height':np.random.randn(10),
                   'Weight':np.random.randn(10),
                   'Gender': ["Male","Male","Male","Male","Male",
                              "Female","Female","Female","Female","Female"]})
p=ggplot(aes(x='Height', y='Weight', color='Gender'), data=df)  + geom_point()
p.make()
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()
fig.set_figwidth(25, forward=True)
plt.show()
```

when I try to save the image, it fails miserably generating a blank image.

```
plt.savefig("image.tiff", dpi=300)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try plt.savefig("image.tiff", bbox_inches='tight') and try to use the sequence plt.savefig("image.tiff", bbox_inches='tight')  
plt.show()  
plt.close()

Comment: This could be caused by [this issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/1524), which is referenced [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092163/error-in-saving-matplotlib-plot-to-tiff). A workaround is always to save as png and convert it to tiff with an external program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully saved the figure to file using the ggplot object [`save`](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/blob/master/ggplot/ggplot.py#L536) method. Here is an example:

```
p.save('image.tiff', width=12, height=8, dpi=144)
```

For more info, see the comment by @Johan in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34599858/3854235) SO response, the source code found [here](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/blob/master/ggplot/ggplot.py#L536), or the example in the [ggplot | docs](https://yhat.github.io/ggpy/docs.html) found [here](https://yhat.github.io/ggpy/notebook.html?page=build/docs/how-to/Saving%20Plots%20to%20a%20File.html).

In terms of setting the on screen size, it doesn't seem like it's possible with the current API. A possible hack is to clone the repo and modify [line 624](https://github.com/yhat/ggpy/blob/master/ggplot/ggplot.py#L624) to be the following:

```
self.fig, self.subplots = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=subplot_kw, figsize=(my_x, my_y)
```

where my_x and my_y are the x and y sizes you'd like for the on screen display. Then use the `show` method:

```
p.show()
```

Comment: Thank you. What I'd like to have is consistent "on screen" and "on file" image size. With p.save I can save the image with the desired width, issue is that on display that image will still remain in a tiny box 4x4.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that the on screen size can be set easily. I just edited my response above to include a possible work around.

Comment: FYI, this option is going away _savefig() got unexpected keyword argument "width" which is no longer supported as of 3.3 and will become an error in 3.6_

Answer (score 0):

did you try with `ggsave(plot = p, filename = 'image.tiff')` or `p.save('image.tiff')`?

**EDIT**
ggsave has been removed from ggplot,use the second solution instead.

Comment: ggsave is not available in ggplot, while p.save ignores the new width I specified with fig.set_figwidth(25, forward=True)

Comment: `p.save(filename, width=None, height=None, dpi=180)`

Comment: Thank you. What I'd like to have is consistent "on screen" and "on file" image size. With p.save I can save the image with the desired width, issue is that on display that image will still remain in a tiny box 4x4.

Comment: could you try with this? `import matplotlib as mpl` and then `mpl.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = "11, 8"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all comments -- this is what ended up working. A little repetition in the code, but it works at last.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from ggplot import *
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Height':np.random.randn(10),
                   'Weight':np.random.randn(10),
                   'Gender': ["Male","Male","Male","Male","Male",
                              "Female","Female","Female","Female","Female"]})
p=ggplot(aes(x='Height', y='Weight', color='Gender'), data=df)  + geom_point()
p.make()
fig = plt.gcf()
ax = plt.gca()

w,h=25,10 #set width and height for both screen and file size

#this part prints on screen the chart
fig.set_figwidth(w, forward=True)  #screen
fig.set_figheight(h, forward=True) #screen
plt.show()

#this part saves it to file
p.save(filename, width=w, height=h, dpi=300) #file
```